# making a condition from a pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a table which contains following columns

```
dependentColumn : values table1.column2, table1.column3, table3.column4....

condition : values ([table1.column2.LAST3][=ABC][OR][=DEF]),
    ([table1.column2.ALL][=ABC]), 
    (([table1.column2][=ABC][OR][table1.column2][!="DEF"])[AND]
        ([table1.column2][!="DEF"]))
 ...

values: abc, [table1.column1.LAST3]
```

Now I need to parse the values contained in condition column and write a code containg the conditions and put the values to the dependentColumns

My concern is making java conditions from the conditions mentioned in the 'condition' column. conditions are stored in a pattern. there can be  multiple conditions whith ANDs and ORs. How do I tackel the problem. I Know its possible but I am a bit confused.Can I use Stack Class, tyhough I have not used it before.

If there is a simple way out to the solution please tell me

Comment: Perhaps some example table data and the desired end result would help clarify?

Comment: There is some missing information - in which form do you have your table? A database table? A spreadsheet? A text file?
And what is your strange condition? Is this stored as text in your table?

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to do from your question but here's my understanding.  It looks like you're trying to encode some values into some db objects described by the "dependentColumn" column of a database table where the values are defined by evaluating a domain-specific language (DSL) encoded in the the "condition" column.

One critical aspect is how complex this DSL is.  A simple language could be parsed by regular expressions and evaluated using a stack as you mentioned but from your example it looks like you could have grouped boolean expressions which might require the use of an actual parser generator (e.g. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)).

Comment: Hi,

I have few tables in the database having few columns each : say table t1 with columns c1, c2, c3. table t2 with columns c1,c2,c3,c4. and so on.
I am viewing all the tables using a Swing Based Application.
Now when I add a value to a table then entry goes in to another table based on some value of a column of a table. I want a solution which is generic and scalable.

Comment: Hence I have a table called TableAction where I store a unique seq no, the name of a table and operation like add, delete , update so that I can tell when to trigger insersion of values in to other table based on the operation made on the parent table. Also I have another table ComplexEntryTable where i store the following dependentColumn : values t1.c2, t1.c3, t3.c4....

Comment: Condition: this column mentions the condition when to put a value to the dependent column. I may have complex conditions as(((t1.c1='abc_def (A-3) nehru road')OR(t2.c1= 'def')) AND (t3.c2='9')), or simple value as [t1.c2][=abc]. This condition is for the base table columns. I am using () for grouping the conditions. How do I tackle the ()s. I have not worked with Stacks much. I just Need some idea as how to go about it.
Regards Krishna